# Showing that if $E$ is a Banach space, and $u \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ then $f(u) = u \circ u \circ u$ is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, differential

> Let $E$ be a Banach space. $\mathcal{L}(E)$ is the space of continuous linear mappings from $E$ to $E$. Let $f: \mathcal{L}(E) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(E)$ such that $$f(u) =  u \circ u \circ u $$
>   Show that $f$ is differentiable.

I am pretty unsure on how to approach this. I know this is a dumb question, but I find it hard to work with differentiability of functions that map to other functions.

Can someone tell me how to approach such a question?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some hints. I am going to use a sufficient condition for differentiability, based on the definition of Gâteaux differentiability.

Recall that $u$ is linear. Hence, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v \in \mathcal{L}(E)$, we can write
$$
(u+tv) \circ (u+tv) = u \circ u + t u \circ v + t v \circ u + v \circ v.
$$
It follows immediately that
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (u+tv) \circ (u+tv) = u \circ v + v \circ u. \tag{1}
$$
Now you must show that the right-hand side of (1) depends continuously on $u \in \mathcal{L}(E)$. This should be rather easy.

Finally, iterate twice to show that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: How to get the differential by iterating, but I am unsure how to show that the right hand side depends continuously on $u$. This is my major difficulty.